# Web scraping: Why is Jupyter Notebook not printing the output of my code?

Tags: python, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook

I'm new to web scraping and still in the "teaching myself" phase. This is an exercise for scraping job titles, etc. from a CraigsList result page. This is exactly what the instructor in the video (taking courses on Udemy) did, and for him, it printed out the details he specified in the code. Yet, when I type out the exact same thing, there is no output.

***However...***
When I tested it out with a quick and short print function, it works. Working while testing it out, but not working in the web-scraping code.

Does anyone here know what the web-scraping code has (or doesn't have) that is preventing the print statement from printing out the output?

the web scraping code in Jupyter Notebook
[image: the web scraping code in Jupyter Notebook]

Things I've already tried:

1. Tested it out in a different browser. I use Brave, and I tried in Chrome. The same thing happens.
2. Restarting the kernel and rerunning the code.
3. Copying and pasting code into a new notebook (file, I guess), then running it there.

Comment: perhaps `jobs` is an empty iterable; try displaying it before iterating over it!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I'll try that.